# Why Require is not defined using WebExtension (Chrome extension for FireFox)

Tags: javascript, google-api, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, firefox-nightly

i'm trying to port Chrome Extension on Nightly(for now) using webextension module , but , when i'm trying to do require("sdk/tabs");

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

tabs.on("ready",function(tabs) {
  if (tabs && tabs.url && tabs.url.match(driveURLpattern) || tabs.url.match(docsURLpattern)) {
    currentTabId = tabs.id;
    return authentication();
  }
```

});

> Console: ReferenceError: require is not defined

But it doesn't work...How can i define it ?

UPDATE: Original code for Chrome is:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
  if (tab && tab.url && tab.url.match(driveURLpattern) || tab.url.match(docsURLpattern)) {
    currentTabId = tab.id;
    return authentication();
  }
}
```

});

Thanks in advance !

eKivOx

**EDIT : SOLUTION WAS FOUND. THANK YOU**

The solution is , require isn't in WebExtensions, we can't do like the SDK-addons , so i've check compatibilities of ChromeAPi and i saw chrome.tabs.onUpdated() is compatible !Cya

Comment: I mean, you're using jpm to create the firefox extension - you've initialised using `jpm init` and testing using `jpm run` etc

Comment: I'm not using the SDK-addon, i've a code for Chrome and i want to change it for Firefox

Comment: `i've a code for Chrome and i want to change it for Firefox` - my mistake, I thought you were trying to create an extension

Comment: I want to do like this : https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/

Comment: you've read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Porting_from_Google_Chrome

Comment: Yes but , Extension need few change , see update post

Comment: I honestly can't keep up with firefox. I thought JPM was needed, but there's no mention of it anywhere in that page ... I give up :p

Comment: I don't know how can i do that...Maybe require is not compatible for now.. :(

Comment: the only incompatibilites with chrome are supposedly here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities

Comment: Yes it's for that , i'm using Chrome.tabs.onUpdate , but not compatible for now , so i've change with tabs.on, like the example but , it doesn't work :(

Comment: If you found a solution that actually addresses this specific question then post an answer and accept it.  Please do not just edit the question to say that you solved it.  Self answered questions are encouraged when you have found a solution to a particular question.  Note that the answer should directly address the specific question you asked, not necessarily a solution that addresses your real need which underlies why you asked the question (these appear to be two separate things in this instance).

Comment: Please share your found solution

Answer (score 1):

require is used in context of CommonJS modules. It imports the methods exported by library modules.
You cannot port your chrome extension to FF-addon as is. You need to create a new Firefox extension using JPM, and within the add-on script, use require

HTH

Comment: Hello , Thank you for answered , I found a solution , i can't require in WebExtension , so i hope many Chrome functions will be available this year ! Thank